# Vs Code won’t open html

Tags: html, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, windows-10

I’ve been using vs code with no problems and all of a sudden it won’t open up my html file in the browser with live server. When I use “open with live server” nothing happens and when I use the option “open in default browser” I get an error “open browser failed!! Please check if you have installed the browser chrome correctly!” And it is. I uninstalled it and installed it again. Restarted my computer and my va code...I’m also on Windows 10.